# Hive/SQL query to extract value of the keyword "swid" from a table struct filed "Details"

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Hive/SQL query to extract value of the keyword "swid" from a table struct filed "Details".

column - "`Details`"

Value  - `"id":123;"name":"Alex";"depID":100;"swid":5456213`

Desired Output:

```
swid
5456213
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using [sts_to_map](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) function:**

```
 with test_data as (select '"id":123\\;"name":"Alex"\\;"depID":100\\;"swid":5456213' as str)

 select str, str_to_map(regexp_replace(str,'\\"',''),'\\;',':')['swid'] as swid from test_data
;
```

Result:

```
OK
str                                                     swid
"id":123;"name":"Alex";"depID":100;"swid":5456213       5456213
Time taken: 0.971 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

**One more solution is to convert to valid JSON (replace semicolon with comma) then use get_json_object to extract element:**

```
with test_data as (select '"id":123\\;"name":"Alex"\\;"depID":100\\;"swid":5456213' as str)

select str, get_json_object(concat('{',regexp_replace(str,'\\;',','),'}'),'$.swid')  as swid from test_data;
OK
str                                                     swid
"id":123;"name":"Alex";"depID":100;"swid":5456213       5456213
Time taken: 6.54 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

**Using `regexp_extract`**:

```
select str, regexp_extract(str,'\\"swid\\":(\\d+)',1) as swid from test_data;
```

Comment: Can we use "str_to_map" function to perform the same filtering in SQL?

Comment: @LalatenduMohanty Not in Hive? Be more specific. What do you mean filtering in SQL

Comment: Thanks for our time. I want to know that How can we get the same result in SQL/MYSQL server.

Comment: @LalatenduMohanty I added one more option. MySQL has regexp_extract function